# C# Http Basic Authentication Bypass

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

On a C# ASP.NET application, I've managed to bypass basic authentication (by sending the username/password through "Authorization" headers on a HTTPWebRequest) and I finally got the unlocked the target page that is protected by htaccess (located on a different server, basic auth) and sent the stream back to the browser.

The issue appears as soon as the user clicks on a link, the basic auth logon box pops up again. We don't want the user to enter to username/password again.

It seems that I need to be sending something back in the headers to tell the browser what username/password it's using for authorization.

I've tried:

- Old "username:password@host" format (insecure, not allowed on IE anymore).
- HTTPWebRequest, which gives me the issue described before.

Considerations:

- The remote server being accessed is a black box.

Is there a way to achieve this? (It can be done in JavaScript as well).

This is my function for the HttpRequest:

```
    public void DoWebRequest(String email, String psw, String hostname, 
    int port, String req_method, String webpage)
    {

    String path = hostname + ":" + port + "/" + webpage;
    String userdata = email + ":" + psw;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(path);
    byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userdata.ToCharArray());
    String req_short_host_temp = hostname;
    String req_short_host = req_short_host_temp.Replace("http://", "");

    Uri uri = new Uri(path);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
    req.Method = req_method;
    req.PreAuthenticate = false;
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 1000");
    req.ReadWriteTimeout = 320000;
    req.Timeout = 320000;
    req.Host = req_short_host;
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, req.Headers, new object[] { "Host", req_short_host });

    var headers = new MyHeaderCollection();
    req.Headers = headers;
    headers.Set("Host", req_short_host);

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    sw.Write("/" + "?user=" + email + "&password=" + psw);
    sw.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();

    foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
    {
        tmp += "\n" + cook.Name + ": " + cook.Value;
    }

    Response.Write(tmp);
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: Do you know any way to achieve this? I'd tried with a cookie but it didn't persist through the html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about javascript, but there is no way in c# to do this I believe. You may filter all user interaction so the browser never accesses the other server directly. To do this, rewrite all urls in content to point to your script (reverse proxy).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd tried this option in two ways during one of my tests.
First test: I edited the html's in the targeted location so each link reffers to the entire targeted location path (for instance, for an original "/Frame.htm" I put "http://chesms.servebeer.com:8800/Frame.htm") but when a user clicks on that link, the login screen appears anyway.
Second test: I also tried replacing those links with the address from where the request was sent (chesms.com.ar), but this gives an 404 error in the server from where the request was sent, which is not correct.